# Need to store bytestring using Django

Tags: python, django, base64

I have a bytestring that i need to store.

Since Django does not support BlobFields I thought I'd create my own Base64Field,
that encodes and decodes to base64 upon interaction with the db.
So I overrode (?) the to_python and get_db_prep_save methods for that exact purpose.

Problem is that to_python gets called in various different scenarios, not just once and
there is no way to tell if the string is already decoded or not. If it is already decoded,
an error obviously occurs.

What solutions are there for my dilema?

Possible solutions that seem ugly to me: try except the decoding process, return value if decoding fails, using an instance variable only allow for 1 to_python (this seems even worse)

Comment: Could you show the methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of [PickledObjectField](http://svn.osqa.net/svnroot/osqa/trunk/forum/models/utils.py).

```
class PickledObjectField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    marker_re = re.compile(r'^T\[(?P<type>\w+)\](?P<value>.*)$', re.DOTALL)
    markable_types = dict((t.__name__, t) for t in (str, int, unicode))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.compress = kwargs.pop('compress', True)
        self.protocol = kwargs.pop('protocol', 2)
        kwargs.setdefault('null', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('editable', False)
        super(PickledObjectField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_type_marked_value(self, value):
        return PickledObject(u"T[%s]%s" % (type(value).__name__, value))

    def read_marked_value(self, value):
        m = self.marker_re.match(value)

        if m:
            marker = m.group('type')
            value = m.group('value')
            if marker in self.markable_types:
                value = self.markable_types[marker](value)

        return value

    def get_default(self):
        if self.has_default():
            if callable(self.default):
                return self.default()
            return self.default

        return super(PickledObjectField, self).get_default()

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            try:
                if value.startswith("T["):
                    value = self.read_marked_value(value)
                else:
                    value = dbsafe_decode(value, self.compress)
            except:
                if isinstance(value, PickledObject):
                    raise
        return value

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, PickledObject):
            if type(value).__name__ in self.markable_types and not (isinstance(value, basestring) and len(value
                                                                                                          ) > MAX_MARKABLE_STRING_LENGTH):
                value = unicode(self.generate_type_marked_value(value))
            else:
                value = unicode(dbsafe_encode(value, self.compress))
        return value

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'TextField'

    def get_db_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if lookup_type not in ['exact', 'in', 'isnull']:
            raise TypeError('Lookup type %s is not supported.' % lookup_type)
        return super(PickledObjectField, self).get_db_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
```